# paste data to activities

Tags: android, android-activity

Nowadays I am creating a new Android app  And I am thinking about one thing. I will have an activity like this :

there are articles. When I click one of them, new Activity will open and put article. I have many articles. Do I have to create new Activities for each of them?
Sorry for my mistakes. I hope you understand. Thanks!

Comment: You typically have an "ArticleDetailFragment" and show the different articles in that.

Comment: You do not have to create new activity for each item...you should use a list view or recycler and pass data. You only need two activities.

Comment: You can use [Fragments](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/fragments) instead of creating new activity.

Comment: Welcome glad to help :)

Comment: i think you look for this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-in-android-application

Comment: Thanks @Xenolion for answer, appreciated